# Regex use replaced string replacement

Tags: php, regex

I have strings like this

```
[Ljava.lang.String;
[Ldummy.class.Here;
[Lanother.unknown.Class;
```

What regex should i use to replace `[L` and `;` with `<span>`,`[]</span>`
And make it look like this

```
<span>java.lang.String[]</span>
<span>dummy.class.Here[]</span>
<span>another.unknown.Class[]</span>
```

What i want is to make java array class string representation more human friendly
I've heard about $1 or something like that, but i couldn't find more information as i don't know what is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$strings = "[Ljava.lang.String;
[Ldummy.class.Here;
[Lanother.unknown.Class;";

$strings = preg_replace('/\[L([A-Za-z\.]+);/', '<span>$1[]</span>', $strings);
echo $strings;
```

Output:

```
$ php foo.php
<span>java.lang.String[]</span>
<span>dummy.class.Here[]</span>
<span>another.unknown.Class[]</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use plain old PHP for this rather than a regex, here is a simple snippet that will do exactly what you need - and you can modify it without having to sort through regex that makes little sense to you:

```
<?php

    $stringArray=array(
        '[Ljava.lang.String;',
        '[Ldummy.class.Here;',
        '[Lanother.unknown.Class;'
        );

    foreach($stringArray as $val)
    {
        $output=$val;
        if($val[0].$val[1]=='[L')
        {
            $output="<span>".substr($val,2);
        }

        if(substr($output,-1)==';')
        {
            $output=substr($output,0,strlen($output)-1).'</span>';
        }

        echo $output.'<br>';
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
<span>java.lang.String</span>
<span>dummy.class.Here</span>
<span>another.unknown.Class</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$new_content = preg_replace('#^\[L(.*);\s*$#m', '<span>$1[]</span>', $content);
```

Demo here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f0de08b5ba0882db2d98d99cdd961b9aebab074

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\[L([^;]+);~', '<span>$1[]</span>', $txt);
```

where `[^;]+` matches all that is not a ";"